# Date Intervals in For each Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What i want is i have 5 records in table, 
dates -> 2017-03-12, 2017-03-23, 2017-03-25, 2017-03-28, 2017-03-29 and they have according price-> 10,20,30,40,50.

I want to generate a report where they show dates between 12 to 29. 12, 13, 14, 15 and so on to 29. with their price, if there is no price available for this date, it should take the previous price record. For an ex, for date 13, 14, 15 it should take the price 10, while for date 24 it should take price 20.

Any Ideas About it?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: So is for specific, coding questions. This is likely to be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$dates['2017-03-12'] = 10;
$dates['2017-03-23'] = 20;
$dates['2017-03-25'] = 30;
$dates['2017-03-28'] = 40;
$dates['2017-03-29'] = 50;

$start = min(array_keys($dates));

$end = max(array_keys($dates));


$list = array();
while($start <= $end){

    $value = $dates[$start];

    if(!is_null($value))
        $last_value = $value;   

    $list[] = array("date" => $start,"value" => $last_value);

    $start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start."+1day"));

}

print_r($list);
```

This will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-12
            [value] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-13
            [value] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-14
            [value] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-15
            [value] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-16
            [value] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-17
            [value] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-18
            [value] => 10
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-19
            [value] => 10
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-20
            [value] => 10
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-21
            [value] => 10
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-22
            [value] => 10
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-23
            [value] => 20
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-24
            [value] => 20
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-25
            [value] => 30
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-26
            [value] => 30
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-27
            [value] => 30
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-28
            [value] => 40
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-29
            [value] => 50
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfect...Hence i implemented different code, because dates are dynamic, so it's not really practical to implement date as keys! yet thankx.

Comment: You can still make the date as keys, just loop your data from your database and create an array with date keys. There are lots of options to achieve the same, it's up to you which you're comfortable to write to ;)